# RAZOR - Remove image tags from variable containing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have below helper to show content.

```
@Html.Raw(Model.PageData.PageContent)
```

I want here to filter out (remove) any image tags it might have. All methods I checked like `.substring()` etc they need specific index or string name to be removed/replace etc. Which is not feasible for me as image tag can have any source attribute etc. is there any possibility with Razor only? I can't modify server side logic that's limitation.

Alternatively, I have to fake it with CSS / JavaScript but I kept these at last.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can easily do that with regular expressions, but it would be better if you remove the images from the model data source, imho.

Comment: What about [Creating a Custom HTML Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) which will do the required work for you.

Comment: @Robert I didn't thought about it... let me give it a try... thanks

Comment: @mmushtaq can't do it... limitation here

Comment: Do not use regex. Use a html parser such as [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved my issue using regular expression. Please suggest if there can be better alternative using razor only without using server side code like c# etc.

```
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
@{
    var news = Model.PageData.PageContent;
    news = Regex.Replace(news, @"<img\s[^>]*>(?:\s*?</img>)?", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
@Html.Raw(news)
```